# Use systemd to start a script at ubuntu 16.04 boot

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, systemd, forever, ubuntu-16.04

I have a simple script "start.sh", which I want to make it auto-boot every time, when ubuntu 16.04 restarts.

I followed this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/773162/i-cant-get-the-right-items-to-boot-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-systemd

And make this simple script: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_run_at_boot

I put it in here.

```
/lib/systemd/system/test_run_at_boot.service
```

I have it linked

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/test_run_at_boot.service -> /lib/systemd/system/test_run_at_boot.service
```

Every time I reboot my machine, it is not starting.

I also try to attach the actual command to test_run_at_boot.service, still not working.

```
[Unit]
Description=test_run_at_boot

[Service]
ExecStart=forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log /home/ubuntu/misc/service/test_run_at_boot/test_run_at_boot.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Update**

In syslog, I got this. `/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory` This causes the script fails at start.

```
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz start.sh[1557]: /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz acpid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz acpid: 1 rule loaded
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz dbus[1590]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Started Cgroup management daemon.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Started FUSE filesystem for LXC.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]: hierarchies: 0: memory
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  1: blkio
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  2: hugetlb
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  3: cpuset
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  4: freezer
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  5: net_cls,net_prio
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  6: pids
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  7: devices
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  8: cpu,cpuacct
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  9: perf_event
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz lxcfs[1624]:  10: name=systemd
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz cron[1648]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Accounts Service...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz cron[1648]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Starting LXD - container startup/shutdown...
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  5 06:45:23 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**Update 1**

I follow this post

https://patrakov.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html

I made some changes

https://github.com/kenpeter/test_run_at_boot/blob/master/test_run_at_boot.service

It is able to start the service after reboot, but after 1 - 2 mins, the service disappear. See below.

```
ubuntu@xyz:~$ ps aux | grep test
root      2155  0.3  3.8 942196 38780 ?        Ssl  13:04   0:00 /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/monitor /home/ubuntu/misc/service/test_run_at_boot/test_run_at_boot.js
ubuntu    3223  0.0  0.1  12944  1092 pts/0    S+   13:05   0:00 grep --color=auto test
ubuntu@xyz:~$ cd misc/
ubuntu@xyz:~/misc/service/test_run_at_boot$ ls
err.log  node_modules  out.log  package.json  start.sh  stop.sh  test_run_at_boot.js  test_run_at_boot.service
ubuntu@xyz:~/misc/service/test_run_at_boot$ ps aux | grep test
ubuntu    3240  0.0  0.0  12944  1012 pts/0    S+   13:05   0:00 grep --color=auto test
ubuntu@xyz:~/misc/service/test_run_at_boot$
```

**Update 2**

In syslog

```
Aug  6 01:24:22 xyz start.sh[1663]: warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
Aug  6 01:24:22 xyz start.sh[1663]: warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
Aug  6 01:24:22 xyz start.sh[1663]: info:    Forever processing file: /home/ubuntu/misc/service/test_run_at_boot/test_run_at_boot.js
Aug  6 01:24:22 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: PID 3347 read from file /home/ubuntu/misc/service/test_run_at_boot/test_run_at_boot.pid does not exist or is a zombie.
....
....
Aug  6 01:24:55 xyz systemd[1]: Started Execute cloud user/final scripts.
Aug  6 01:24:55 xyz systemd[1]: Reached target Cloud-init target.
Aug  6 01:25:00 xyz ntpdate[2709]: adjust time server 91.189.91.157 offset 0.104466 sec
Aug  6 01:25:51 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug  6 01:25:51 xyz systemd[1]: Failed to start test_run_at_boot.
Aug  6 01:25:51 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug  6 01:25:51 xyz systemd[1]: test_run_at_boot.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Comment: Have you enabled the service with `systemctl enable`?

Comment: normally `nodejs` on Ubuntu

Comment: and you don't really need forever when you have systemd

Comment: and this is more a question for [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Using forever under systemd is a bit like using forever to run forever.

Without forever, the systemd config becomes simpler.

```
[Unit]
Description=test_run_at_boot

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /home/ubuntu/misc/service/test_run_at_boot/test_run_at_boot.js
Type=oneshot
#Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The test script you are using is a [`Type=oneshot`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=) as the script is expected to exit, otherwise systemd will report the service as failed.  Once you have a long running service to manage you can remove `Type=oneshot` and use `Restart=on-failure` to keep the service up, like forever does.

`stderr` and `stdout` from the process are sent to the systemd journal. On Ubuntu this goes to syslog.

If there are features of forever you really need, then systemd requires a bit more setup. The [`Type` becomes `forking`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=). You will need to setup a `--pidFile` and have a matching systemd [`PIDFile=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#PIDFile=) as well.